# utf8.offset: how to specify starting positions?

Tags: utf-8, lua, lua-5.3

How can I use `utf8.offset(s, n, i)` to find the offset of the character at `n` starting from specific byte and character positions? The `i` parameter is documented as:

> Returns the position (in bytes) where the encoding of the n-th character of s (counting from position i) starts...

I got `i` is what I need, but I can't understand if it's byte position or character position. How can I use it?

Comment: `i` is byte position (starting from 1).  You can use result returned by `utf8.offset` as value for `i` in the next invocation of `utf8.offset(s, n, i)` for the same `s`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks! So Lua caches the string in this function, correct?

Comment: No, Lua does not cache the string.  It just starts to parse the string from byte position you specified in argument `i`, that's why you can use it in step-by-step manner to avoid unnecessary parsing.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Hum, so, for example, the position 1 is equivalent to `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All string offsets in the Lua manual are in bytes, unless the manual specifically says otherwise. So `i` is a byte offset, as is `utf8.offset`'s return value.

Comment: Further more, will `i` be the starting position? Something like `1 == i`.

Comment: @PolarDigit: It says what `i` is right in the documentation: "counting from position i".